# Не запускаются скрипты через консоль

Tags: node.js

Поставил nodejs пытаюсь выполнить простейший скрипт. Для этого ввожу

[image: скриншот консоли]

После ввода команды

```
E:\nodejs> node 1.js
```

Содержимое файла `1.js`:

```
console.log('Hello world');
```

Происходит открытие еще 1 терминала я так понимаю, но оно тут же мгновенно скрывается и все ни какого результата в этом терминале я не вижу.
Помогите настроить.

**Обновление**

[Выполняю](http://prntscr.com/8nw8ll) команду по добавлению пути, потом пишу `node -v`, и опять что-то быстро открывается и тут же сворачивается, ни какой информации в ту консоль откуда я производил запуск команды не происходит. Кстати фай node.exe отлично работает, и оттуда я могу запускать простые команды типа 1+1, но вот как оттуда запустить другие скрипты и вообще возможно ли  я не знаю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте то, что вы вводите в консоль и ответ системы прямо в вопрос (и не картинкой).

Answer (score 2):

Судя по Вашему описанию скрипт отрабатывается и тут же закрывается. Для того чтобы этого не происходило нужно выполнять скрипт от nodejs в уже открытой консоли.

Добавьте в PATH nodejs, вводя в консоль следующую команду:

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

Tеперь попробуйте выполнить

```
node -v
```

Если в консоли появится версия nodejs, выполняйте следующую команду:

```
node путь/до/файла/node.js
```

**Обновление**

У Вас почему-то `nodejs` запускается в отдельном окне и выполняет все скрипты там, а выполнившись сразу же закрывает консоль.

В таком случае попробуйте в папке, где лежит `node.exe` на пустом пространстве нажать "shift + правая кнопка мыши" и выбрать в меню "Командная строка" что-то там (сейчас под рукой нет windows). У Вас откроется командная строка из папки где вы её вызвали. Напишите что-то навроде:

```
node.exe путь/до/файла/node.js
```

Comment: Сделал так как Вы написали опять что то блымкнуло и сразу исчезло http://prntscr.com/8ny09v

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8nxyjj
просто вел команду node и он открыл мне консоль от node, мне кажется он в ней и выполняет тот мой скрипт и результат выводит не в cmd а в свой node командную строку

Answer (score 1):

Для Windows 10, нужно отключить UAC в regedit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Параметр `EnableLUA` нужно установить на занчение 0.

После, сохранить и перезапустить ваш ПК.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, переведите ответ на русский язык, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

> Происходит открытие еще 1 терминала я так понимаю, но оно тут же мгновенно скрывается и все ни какого результата в этом терминале я не вижу. Помогите настроить.

```
node 1.js & pause
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8obp12 все равно не работает